# Python Scikit-image Install Failing Using Pip

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

I'm attempting to install scikit-image and am obtaining this error output message. I'm unsure how to actually display the text properly, so just a simple paste I have done.

```
building 'skimage.external.tifffile._tifffile' extension
    compiling C sources
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\skimage\external
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\skimage\external\tifffile
    C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG /arch:SSE2 -Ic:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcskimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\skimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.obj
    tifffile.c
    skimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.c(75) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
    error: Command "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG /arch:SSE2 -Ic:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcskimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\skimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Issue was stdint.h was not installed with the VS Python setup.

To solve this, visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattn/gntp-send/master/include/msinttypes/stdint.h

Copy and paste the text into a notepad document/text editor and save it to
C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include\

Save it as stdint.h

Comment: what if that path does not exists ?

Comment: You probably need the visual c++ download then to be installed on your system. Right now I also don't have that path on my new system, all from not having VS downloaded